# C# - Convert a string of hex values to hex

Tags: c#, string, byte, hex

This might sound odd, but my issue is that I have a text string of hex values from a text file, like so:

```
"0x0f, 0x40, 0xff, ...."
```

I have stored them in an array split by the delimiters, but what I now need to do is have a byte array of what thay are in hex:

```
stringArray[0] = "0x0f";

byteArray[0] = 0x0f;
```

How do I do this (the user can load the text file, so I don't know what the values are), is there some sort of arithmetic I can use?

Comment: The question itself is valid in my opinion. Closing won't make him accept more answers, I guess. user646265: Please accept more answers that helped you. This will make more people want to help you.

Comment: Yes, I would have done, but I only just got above the 15 reputation that you need to accept answers. I will do so in future, now I am at 16 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to parse each string. Because each one is already only one value, you can do this:

```
byte b;
if (byte.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out b)) 
{
    // b contains the value.
}
```

where s is the string you want to parse, and b is the resulting value.

Comment: Thanks. When I get enough reputation points, I'll vote up your answer.

Comment: I'll add that sadly the response is wrong. `byte.TryParse` doesn't support the 0x format. Read it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) `HexNumber Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, and AllowHexSpecifier styles are used` and `AllowHexSpecifier Strings that are parsed using this style cannot be prefixed with "0x" or "&h"`

Answer (score 3):

If your string is in the correct format you can create your array using this code (will throw exceptions if the input is badly formatted):

```
var text = "0x0f, 0x40, 0xff";
var bytes = text
  .Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
  .Select(s => (Byte) Int32.Parse(s.Substring(2), AllowHexSpecifier));
```

Answer (score 0):

Non of Odd hex string is correct.
Check source from you get this string .
It is because of truncation of string due to limit no of characters.
If String is **image is stored in database then retrieve it using program not using any tools**

I was having same problem with .net and MSSQL and by using webservice and Java Client