# String to byte converting

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Covert String of Hex values to Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647328/c-sharp-covert-string-of-hex-values-to-hex)

I want to convert from str= "0x04" to byte cmd = 0x04; 
How can I do it in c sharp?
What i want is to convert string value and write it to COM Port, like this:

```
byte[] val;
val = new byte[16];
byte[] res4 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str4);
val[0] = 0xFF;
val[1] = 0xFF;
...
val[15] = 0x01;
port.Write(val, 0, 16);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a note, the duplicated question has the wrong answer. Tsabo is right.

Answer (score 2):

To get a byte value from a string like that, you can use:

```
byte b = Byte.Parse(str.Remove(0,2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Basicly you need to remove the 0x part of the string, and then specify that you are parsing a Hexadecimal value

Comment: If byte b = Byte.Parse(str4.Remove(0,2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);  What is the difference between val[0] = 0x04 and val[0] = b ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int num = System.Convert.ToInt32(str4, 16);
byte[] val = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
```

Comment: Convert String to int first; then int to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string with Int32.Parse() as an hexadecimal number. If the string is composed by multiple *commands* you have to split it with String.Split().