# Hex format in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Convert a string of hex values to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647328)

I converted the following code from Visual Basic to C#. But how do I know how I can use **Hex** in C#?

```
private string ConvertStringToHex(string sText)
{
    int lCount;
    string sHex;
    string sResult;
    for (lCount = 1; (lCount <= sText.Length); lCount++)
    {
        sHex = Hex(Convert.ToInt32(sText.Substring((lCount - 1), 1)));
        if ((sHex.Length == 1))
        {
            sHex = ("0" + sHex);
        }
        sResult = (sResult + sHex);
    }
    return sResult;
}
```

Comment: you need to search for "converting string to byte array".

Comment: Does this code work? Have you tried running this code? what error you get?

Comment: Just i converted. i did not run that code. it is showing Hex is not in  the context.

Comment: Let me know why i got -1 for my question.

Comment: Hey, was it VB or VB.NET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want to convert to hexadecimal, then you can probably do it like:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(sText);
string hexval = val.ToString("X");
```

`Hex()` is a function for returning a string representing the hexadecimal value of a number avilable in VB/[VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET).

See *[Hex Function (Visual Basic)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130802011513/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963zt96e(v=vs.80).aspx)* (MSDN).