# How to pass dynamic value to byte array

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, serial-communication

Here is my code:

```
private void send_char_0(string R, string G, string B)
        {
            string r = R;
            string g = G;
            string b = B;
            string strData = null;
            int i = 0;
            byte[] data_array = new byte[3]{0xff,0xef,0xff};
        }
```

I have brought hexvalues in string R,G,B respectively but when i pass them
`byte[] data_array = new byte[3]{R,G,B};` **-> error string cannot be converted to byte.**

So i tried to convert  **dataarray[0] = Convert.ToByte(R)** i.e `Convert.ToByte(0xff)`**--> error Input string is not in proper format as 0xff .** needs to have "ff" but i need to pass it as "oxff" to serial port.

Anyone can help me

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647328/c-sharp-convert-a-string-of-hex-values-to-hex

Comment: This is not javascript.

Comment: Why do you pass bytes as strings into function?

Comment: As i am taking values of R,G,B from  UI  through javascript in form of string and when i need to pass bytes data to serial port i need to convert 0xff of 255 to send as bytes

Answer (score 0):

You are passing strings into array of bytes.
Try this:

```
private void send_char_0(string R, string G, string B)
{
    byte r = byte.Parse(R,NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    byte g = byte.Parse(G,NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    byte b = byte.Parse(B,NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    byte[] data_array = new byte[3]{r,g,b};
 }
```

You probably will need to add some check if this data is correct, as it cames from user,

Comment: Hi Alex , But it still gives me error "Input string is not in correct format" as we are trying to convert 0xff to byte . I tried with NumberStyle.AllowHexSpecifier but not working